# combine three videos between specific time using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a situation where I want to combine 3 videos

The first video `(guide.mp4)` is the guide and the other 2 are small pieces that need to go inside the "guide".

In a graphical manner, I have the following

```
|         .---1.mp4---.                            .-----2.mp4-----.    |
|---------+-----------+------------guide.mp4-------+--------------------|
0s        4s          9s                          18s             25s   28s
```

The `1.mp4` and `2.mp4` will cover the guide between these times. the videos are of same size and all are .mp4 files

I am pretty sure that this is covered, but I looked a lot, but since I myself am not good in english, I dont know how I could possibly look it up with success...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show information about your inputs. The complete output of `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i guide.mp4` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a single command to do all of this but because you're trying to trim and combine clips the simplest method I could find was to break the process into three parts. Start by using ffmpeg to trim the guide clip into 3 sections like this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i guide.mp4 -t 5 guide-out-1.mp4
$ ffmpeg -i guide.mp4 -ss 00:09 -t 9 guide-out-2.mp4
$ ffmpeg -i guide.mp4 -ss 00:25 -t 3 guide-out-3.mp4
```

and then to combine the clips you need to make a text file called video-list.txt such that:

```
$ cat video-list.txt
file 'guide-out-1.mp4'
file '1.mp4'
file 'guide-out-2.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file 'guide-out-3.mp4'
```

finally use ffmpeg again to combine them all into one clip:

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i video-list.txt -c copy new-guide.mp4
```

Comment: I tried splitting the videos add puting them all together, but I need to keep the sound of guide.mp4 and if I split it then the sound is no more synced!

Comment: @Krisi What should be done with the sound from the other inputs? I'm not sure if there is any, but this is one reason why I always ask for the console output (and info about the inputs when using concat demuxer).

Comment: @Krisi the short answer is that what you're trying to do is significantly easier using real video editing software. But if you want to do it all in ffmpeg you'll just need to extract the audio from those seconds of guide.mp4 and add it into 1.mp4 and 2.mp4. If you want to update the question I can help with the commands.
Alternately you can try the overlay method described here: http://www.daniel-mitchell.com/blog/video-in-a-video-ffmpeg/

Comment: @Krisi If the sound from Guide.mp4 needs to remain all through, overlay video (picture only) at those insertion points.